# Say that a tournament T has 2-property, if for every distinct vertices u, w ∈ V ( T ), T has a (directed) u,w-path of length exactly 2.

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, directed-graphs

Say that a tournament T has 2-property, if for every distinct vertices $u,w \in V(T)$, T has a (directed) u,w-path of length exactly 2. (In particular, if T has 2-property, then every vertex of T is a king. But not every tournament in which each vertex is a king has 2-property.) Determine the least positive integer n $\geq$ 2 such that some n-vertex tournament T has 2-property. (Hint: show that each in-degree and out-degree in such tournament must be at least 3, and then present a construction.)

I'm confused on the idea that 2-property would mean every vertex is a king but not that a tournament with each vertex is a king has 2-property. Does this mean we can't have u,w path of length of 1 at all but every path should be exactly two? How do we tackle this? Do we just add loops to each vertex? Please help! Thanks!

Comment: It just means that, for any vertices $u$ and $v,$ there is at least one $u,v$-path of length $2.$ That doesn't mean there can't be other $u,v$-paths of length $1$ or $2$ or $17.$ It just means what it says. What's confusing about that? In the cyclic tournament  on $3$ vertices, every vertex is a king, but it's not a $2$-tournament.

Comment: You should supply the definition of a king, which is a vertex that can reach all others with a path of length $1$ or $2$.  The $2-$property says every vertex can reach every other with a path of length exactly $2$.  The contrast is that for a king you have the option of a path of length $1$.  bof has given a good example that has every vertex a king but does not have the $2-$ property.

Comment: Consider a vertex $w.$ Since $n\ge2$ $w$ can't be a sink; there must be an arc $wx.$ Since $T$ has the $2$-property, there's a path of length $2$ from $w$ to $x,$ so we have arcs $wy$ and $yx.$ Since there's a path of length $2$ from $w$ to $y,$ we also have arcs $wz$ and $zy;$ the arcs $wx,wy,wz$ show that $w$ has outdegree at least $3.$ (Of course there is also a path of length $2$ from $w$ to $z$ but that could go $wxz,$ so it doesn't increase the out-degree.) Similarly, the indegree is at least $3,$ so $n\ge7.$ Now construct a tournament on $7$ vertices with the $2$-property.

Comment: Call the vertices $t,u,v,w,x,y,z.$ You may as well start by drawing arcs $wx,wy,wz$ and $yx,zy,xy$ and $tw,uw,vw.$ That's already $9$ of the $21$ arcs, so you're $43\%$ done. Can you finish it?

Comment: Thanks bof. I got it right now. The troubling part was I can't think of any uw path that is exactly 2 but not other lengths. Thx again.